# How do I tell Windows 7 not to default install software in C:\?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I installed a 60GB SSD for the Windows 7 OS.  I want to keep most software off it and install to the D:\ drive.  Can I change the default installation drive?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the registry key of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir
```

from c:\Program Files to whatever you want to be your default install folder

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.  Most software will let you install to another drive though at installation time if you choose custom.  But you can't force it because it uses the %HOMEDRIVE% environment variable and if you change that, Windows will cease to function.

According to Microsoft, [this functionality is by design.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841343)

Comment: Plus some programs just hardcode it.

Comment: I think it is more likely that installers default to `%PROGRAMFILES%`.